# Run generated makefile without CMake installed

Tags: makefile, cmake

I want to compile my program on our university HCP server, I created it as a CMake project on my laptop but the server does not have CMake installed and I can not install it (limited storage).

How do I compile the project on the server without CMake and only `make`?

I ran `cmake` command on my laptop and then transferred the sources and  generated `Makfile` to the server, but when I execute `make` on the server it complains about `cmake` missing:

```
make: /usr/local/bin/cmake: Command not found
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 127
```

Is it possible to generate a Makefile that can run only `make` and does not need CMake installed?

Comment: The makefile generated by CMake depends on CMake itself.

Comment: So you have enough space to build the project but not enough to install `cmake`?

Comment: If you can't install CMake why even trying using it ? Just write a Makefile, it perfectly does the job even for large projects. I don't want to start (yet another) a `CMake vs make` war but if you can't install CMake you don't have much choice.

Comment: @TimF To hazard a guess, OP may want to use CMake as alternative to autotools (which don't require "user" to have them, make is enough).

Comment: thank you, I thought the generated Makefile can be used without Cmake and just make!! so I was wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, for two major reasons:

- As pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167079/makefile-generated-by-cmake-does-not-work#comment83313335_48167079), the generated Makefiles will again attempt to call CMake during the build.
- Besides that, Makefiles generated by CMake are not supposed to be portable. A Makefile generated on one machine is likely to break when copied to another.

Note that CMake has no mandatory external dependencies, so you should be able to quickly build a local copy from source on the server and use that to build your project. If that is for whatever reason not feasible, you cannot use CMake and will have to rely on a different method for building, like writing your own ad-hoc Makefile from scratch.